# FlatList detect item on scroll

Tags: react-native

I have a FlatList with Headers and Items.

I'm trying to detect when headers touch the top of screen to execute a specific function.

This is my code:

```
  const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Header',
      isHeader: true
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'First Item',
      isHeader: false
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Second Item',
      isHeader: false
    },
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'Second Header',
      isHeader: true
    },
  ];

onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {

  viewableItems.forEach((item) => {

    console.log(item['item']['id'] + ' / Is header: ' + item['item']['isHeader'])

  });

}
```

FlatList:

```
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
  />
```

So, what can I do to detect which item is touching the top of screen? I tried to search, but I had no success.

Comment: making use `onViewableItemsChanged`

Comment: It didn't work for me. When I have a small list, all items are returned. I'll update my question to include the code I tried